# Filtering in Python/Django based on date, ignoring time

Tags: python, django, datetime-format

I'd like to filter objects to the day with datetime, but can't find examples on how to do this anywhere.

This, for example, works perfectly in pulling together all following events:

```
@login_required
def invoice_picker(request):
    """Grab a date from the URL and show all the invoicable deliveries for that day."""
    query = request.GET.get('q' , '2/9/1984')
    date = datetime
    date = datetime.strptime('7/14/2010', '%m/%d/%Y')
    date = date.strptime(query, '%m/%d/%Y')
    results = []
    if query:
        results = LaundryDelivery.objects.filter(end__gte=date)
    return render_to_response('invoicer.html', {
        'results' : results,
        'date' : date,
        'user' : request.user,
    })
```

But when I remove __gte, it returns nothing because the dates are along the lines of 2010-06-22 04:04:00 instead of 2010-06-22 00:00:00. I also tried:

```
 results = LaundryDelivery.objects.filter(end.date=date)
```

but unfortunately I get the error "keyword can't be an expression". Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's a good way to compare datetimes with dates.  One way is the following:

```
filter(end__year=date.year, end__month=date.month, end__day=date.day)
```

The other is to use the [`range`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#range) lookup with the min time and max time for the day.